# UITableView tableViewHeader does not respect the table safearea

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I set constraints of a vStack (UIStackView) relative to my view `safeAreaLayout`.
The view is used as the `tableHeaderView` of a `UITable`.
The parent safeArea is not respected by the headerView, resulting in misalignment.

How does one fix this ?

Here's the constraints set-up, it's done in the `init` of the view

```swift
let vStack = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
vStack.axis = .vertical
vStack.alignment = .leading
vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addSubview(vStack)

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
} else {
    vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}

vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 48).isActive = true
vStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
```

Comment: Have you looked at [preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622653-preservessuperviewlayoutmargins)?

Comment: :| I actually thought I tried that. Friday night is not a good time to be working 

But then one shouldn't use `safeAreaLayoutGuide` but just the `layoutMarginGuide`